# Why is the master data service from SQL Server 2016 creating a text field as the primary ID?

Tags: master-data-services

If I create a new entity from excel, or from the UI and select "Generate code automatically" for the Code attribute, MDS creates an attribute of the type "Free-form - Data Type : Text, Length : 250" !? Why not "Number, Decimals: 0"?

Answer (score 0):

MDS does not give you control over the attribute types for the two default fields 'Name' and 'Code' on any entity. That is unfortunately how it was designed.

In the back-end, MDS actually uses integers as the primary keys for the entities it generates. You can look at how this is done by creating a subscription view in the web-app, and then logging onto the database with SSMS and scripting the view you created. You will see a few more attributes created and used.